# python-pptx content remove bullet

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Using `python-pptx`, I created a slide that contains a title and content. The content has a bullet point by default. How do I remove this bullet point?

```
prs = pptx.Presentation()
slide = _add_slide(prs, 'Title and Content')
slide.placeholders[0].text = "Title"
slide.placeholders[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0].text = "Content"
prs.save('presentation.pptx')
```

Reference: https://www.kaggle.com/code/x68000/tipsforpythonppt#Modify-font-

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you wanted to use placeholders? You could use a different slide layout or even a blank slide layout and place textboxes etc yourself. There isn't a straight forward way to remove the bullet point and instead relies on editing the xml like so...

```
import pptx
from lxml import etree


prs = pptx.Presentation()
layout = prs.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[1]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(layout)
slide.placeholders[0].text = "Title"
slide.placeholders[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0].text = "Content"
slide.placeholders[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = pptx.util.Pt(64)
slide.placeholders[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.bold = True
slide.placeholders[1].text_frame.paragraphs[0]._pPr.insert(0, etree.Element("{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}buNone"))
prs.save('presentation.pptx')
```